# Issue in Sending mail in Bulk quantity in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, openssl

I am trying to create a bulk email sender. I want the script to open form.csv that contains multiple email addresses, and send the email to them.
Problem is after sending 75 to 80 mails its give an error, total no of mail is (1000)

Simply, I need help to send more and sends the email to those addresses.
below is the src code its working fine.enter code here

```
import csv, smtplib, ssl

port = 587
smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
login = "example@gmail.com"     # paste your login
password = "jjshajcaez"         # paste your password

message = """Subject: Happy New Year

To: {recipient}
From: {sender}

Dear {name},
We wish you and your family a very Happy New Year!

With warm regards, """

sender = "example@gmail.com"

context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port) as server:
    server.connect('smtp.gmail.com', '587')
    server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
    server.starttls(context=context)
    server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted   
    server.login(login, password)
    with open("form.csv") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        next(reader)  # it skips the header row
        for name, email in reader:
            server.sendmail(
               sender,
               email,
               message.format(name=name, recipient=email, sender=sender)
            )
            print(f'Sent to {name}')


form.csv
#name, email
Test, test@gmail.com
```

is there any suggestion how to modify the code... so that it can send mail at once and store the log file on the system.

Comment: What error are you getting? Also - gmail allows only 500 emails per day https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22839